# How to use STATS_GETR extension command in SPSS

Tags: r, spss

I have recently installed the the STATS_GETR extension command in SPSS.

Once I go to 'File' then 'Get R Workspace' what exactly do I need to do in order to open an .Rdata file?

I do not have a Workspace created, and I do not know how to figure out the Data frame of the dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extension command actually has a helper subcommand `INFO` to help with that problem. So here is an example running it on an `RData` file I created that is simply the saved workspace of `MyDF <- data.frame(cbind(rnorm(100),rnorm(100)))`.

```
STATS GET R FILE="C:\Users\andrew.wheeler\Desktop\test\Examp.RData"
  /INFO.
```

Note the workspace *is* the `RData` file. So if you have an `RData` file you have created the "workspace". The command above will print all of the available objects in that particular file.

Once you figure out which object contains the data you want, then you can run the command below to grab that data frame. In this example I grab the `MyDF` dataframe.

```
STATS GET R FILE = "C:\Users\andrew.wheeler\Desktop\test\Examp.RData"
  /GET DATAFRAME=MyDF DATASET=SPSSMyDF.
```

As always, see `STATS GET R /HELP` to see all of the options.